# I am using OpenXML in C# for creating xlsx file but date comes as Jan 1900

Tags: openxml, spreadsheet

In C# I am using `OpenXML` document format spreadsheet to create xlsx file. but excel gets created with date 'Jan 1900'. I am applying stylesheet document to spreadsheet document. Please help to get exact date.

I expects date should be `01/01/2019` which comes from datatable but actual output is `Jan 1900`

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to output the date to the cell? What format are you using? What value are you outputting?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the solutions is to use the `TEXT` function.
Let's say you have a variable contains the date named `dDate`.
Then, put this in the cell where you want the value to be displayed:
`=text(dDate,"mm/dd/yyyy")`
Maybe you need to use C# grammar to do the concatenation of the string and the variable.